# Merge two docker run commands together

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mount, docker-machine

I have two docker run commands as given below but I would like to merge these two commands together and execute it.

**1st command** - Start orthanc just with web viewer enabled

```
docker run -p 8042:8042 -e WVB_ENABLED=true osimis/orthanc
```

**2nd command** - Start Orthanc with mount directory tasks

```
 docker run -p 4242:4242 -p 8042:8042 --rm --name orthanc -v 
 $(pwd)/orthanc/orthanc.json:/etc/orthanc/orthanc.json -v 
 $(pwd)/orthanc/orthanc-db:/var/lib/orthanc/db jodogne/orthanc-plugins 
 /etc/orthanc --verbose
```

As you can see, in both the cases the Orthanc is being started but I would like to merge these into one and start Orthanc. When it is started Web viewer should also be enabled and mount directory should also have happened

Can you let me know on how can this be done?

Comment: Aside from using `docker-compose` (preferred), you can join the 2 commands with `&&` as after all they are just bash commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `docker-compose`, it is specially targeted for running multiple containers.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  osimis:
    image: osimis/orthanc
    environment: 
      WVB_ENABLED: 'true'
    ports:
      - 8042:8042

  orthanc:
    image: jodogne/orthanc-plugins
    environment: 
      WVB_ENABLED: 'true'
    ports:
      - 4242:4242
      - 8042:8042
    volumes:
      - ./orthanc/orthanc.json:/etc/orthanc/orthanc.json
      - ./orthanc/orthanc-db:/var/lib/orthanc/db
    command: /etc/orthanc --verbose
```

and `docker-compose up` to finish the work

Comment: Can you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56610107/integrate-two-docker-apps-docker-compose-and-docker-run